# How to get flow control back in controller after downloading file in spring MVC

Tags: java, web-services, file, spring-mvc, download

I am using file download funtionality in my web application based on Spring MVC.

How ?

1. Getting file from SOAP web service in controller .
2. Using ServletContext object to download file.

**Question:**

Control is not getting back in controller, I want to do more task  in controller after downloading file.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Basically I have implemented download and delete functionality separately. Now I want to implement archive funtionality by using download and delete funtionality simultaneously.  But when file get downloaded control doesn't get back to execute delete functionality.....